# Suddenly can't connect to remote mlab mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to a remote [mlab](https://mlab.com/home) database. Everything works fine, except for some times I simply can’t connect to the database. It might have something to do with my computer since my test server can connect to it without any problems. Nevertheless I can’t figure out what the problem might be. I went through their [connection troubleshooting guide](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help) but already got stuck at the first step

```
nc -w 3 -v ds119568.mlab.com 19568
```

gives the following error:
    nc: connectx to ds119568.mlab.com port 19568 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out

```
Trying to connect via mongo shell gives this error:
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://ds119568.mlab.com:19568/ba
2017-07-08T15:05:04.528+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
54.73.159.50:19568 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-07-08T15:05:04.533+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server ds119568.mlab.com:19568, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Advice what on what could be the problem here? Does it have something to do with the firewall of my computer?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04) :

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Doesn't give output. Check the status to verify that the service has started properly.

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Output should be something like:

```
    ● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-17 18:57:26 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 2811 (mongod)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 56.8M
      CPU: 7.294s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─2811 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Verify that its running:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Output should be:

```
 Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service
to /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service.
```

Then you should be able to connect to mongo shell.

```
mongo
```

For more refer to this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: The question is regarding a hosted MongoDB, not how to run MongoDB on your own server.